# Issues with Vimeo player

Tags: vimeo

Here i am including a video on page in below manner. Till 2 to 3 weeks before this is working fine, but now it is causing issues

```html
<iframe id="frmQuoteBgVdo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/126591886?autoplay=1&loop=1&api=1&player_id=frmQuoteBgVdo" width="100%" height="1200" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes around June July 2016 vimeo released its new api.

This introduced changes in the way to embed videos, for instance you're not supose to add `api=1` or `player_id=xxx`

I doubt it's the origin of you issue but you may try

```
<iframe id="frmQuoteBgVdo" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/126591886?autoplay=1&loop=1" width="100%" height="1200" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Cheers